# How to find antilogarithm for large values?

Tags: python, pow, modular-arithmetic, exp

I want to know how to find antilogarithm of a float.
My first approach was to use built-in functions like exp(), pow() both in Python & C, but they gave out of range error.

Then I tried to break It in two parts, one integer & other float, then calculate 10 raise to the power separately for both of them & then multiply them to get the result.
so when I try to calculate (a*b) in Python It says **long int too large to convert to float**

My Original task was to calculate antilog(x)%m & I converted it (a*b)%m where a is very very large integer & b is float.

So can anyone help me out with this?
Is there any modular property that applies on floats?
Or is there any "fast" & "efficient" way to calculate antilog(x)?

Comment: how large? How much precision?

Comment: x will be around 1500... I'm not sure, but minimum value of x will be around 700 (as It is calculated in an intermediate step of my question, so I'm not that much sure about It). Precision doesn't matter as finally I want my answer to be integer, but that should round of to correct integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to calculate `(10**x)%m`, don't try to compute `10**x` first.  The [pow](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow) function takes three arguments:

> pow(x, y[, z])
>
> Return x to the power y; if z is present, return x to the power y, modulo z (computed more efficiently than pow(x, y) % z). The two-argument form pow(x, y) is equivalent to using the power operator: x**y.

This seems perfect for your problem.  You want `pow(10, x, m)`

OOPS: except you have a non-integral exponent.

Can't you use these equalities:

1. `a**(b+c) == a**b * a**c`
2. `(a*b)%m == (a%m * b%m) % m`

to define a function like this:

```
def bigpow(a, b, m):
    bint = int(b)
    bfrac = b - int(b)
    return (pow(a, bint, m) * ((a**bfrac)%m)) % m
```

Comment: I ran your suggestion in python & it says: **pow() 3rd argument not allowed unless all arguments are integers**

Comment: Ah, sorry, I overlooked that your exponent was a float.

Comment: So you have any other suggestion?

Comment: I tried that also.
For example let a=1000 & b=3.125 & m=24
((a%m)*(b*m))%m = 2

but answer should have been 5, coz 3125%24=5

Modular arithmetic works on integers only...